# JSON combinator for array

Tags: playframework

For this JSON

```
{
  "dokvotering": {
    "votering": [
      {
        "rm": "2013/14",
        "beteckning": "AU2"
      },
      {
        "rm": "2013/14",
        "beteckning": "AU2"
      }
    ]
   }
}
```

I am trying to create a using a JSON  combinator like so

```
  import play.api.libs.json._
  import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
  import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
  import play.api.data.validation.ValidationError


  implicit val dokVoteringReads: Reads[DokVotering] = (
(__ \ "docvotering" \ "Votering" ).lazyRead( list[Votering](voteringReads) )
    )(DokVotering)

  implicit val voteringReads:Reads[Votering] = (
      (__ \ "Votering" \ "rm").read[String] ~
      (__ \ "Votering" \ "beteckning").read[String] 
    )(Votering)
}




case class DokVotering(votering: List[Votering])

case class Votering(
            rm: String,
            beteckning: String
                )
```

Which errors out with :

```
Error:(23, 7) type mismatch;
 found   : se.ce.dto.DokVotering.type
 required: play.api.libs.json.Reads[?]
    )(DokVotering)
      ^
```

Whats the right way to do a combinator for this array structure?

Comment: Can you post the definitions of `Votering` and `DokVotering`?

Comment: http://data.riksdagen.se/Data/Voteringar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do it your way, there seems to be a problem because `DokVotering` has no other attributes than the list of `Votering`s. If you add another parameter, everything's fine. Otherwise, you'll have to change your implicit reads a bit:

```
implicit val voteringReads: Reads[Votering] = (
  (JsPath \ "rm").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "beteckning").read[String]
  )(Votering.apply _)

implicit val dokVoteringReads: Reads[DokVotering] =
  (JsPath \ "dokvotering" \ "votering").read[List[Votering]] map (DokVotering.apply _)
```

Or, if you like, you can use Play's magic [JSON Macro Inception](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonInception) feature. (Well, it's not really magic, but it uses Scala macros and largely *feels* like magic.)
Using this feature, your implicits get defined based on your case classes for `Votering` and `DokVotering`. Like this:

```
implicit val voteringReads = Json.reads[Votering]
implicit val dokVoteringReads = Json.reads[DokVotering]
```

The only thing is, this doesn's handle the nested nature of your JSON, so you would do the transformation like this:

```
(json \ "dokvotering").validate[DokVotering] match {...}
```

to accomodate for that.